# Ctrl-C doesn't interrupt semaphore.acquire

Tags: python, multithreading, semaphore

```
while True:
    try:
        queries_semaphore.acquire()
        query = queries.pop(0)
        # Do some stuff ...
        info('Query executed: `%s\'' % str(query))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        okay('quit')
        break
```

The problem is that `KeyboardInterrupt` is raised only *after* `queries_semaphore.acquire()` returns, so a user isn't able to break the program with Ctrl-C. What's a good solution in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create another thread for queries_semaphore.acquire() part and leave main thread for interaction with user. If user hit Ctrl-C then you should unblock working thread by setting semaphore and finish it.

Comment: While this sort of works, the spawned process still makes the main thread wait for the child. So you need to kill that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread explains how to do that.